# Reduce dynamically some portion of string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a C# program that will do something like this..

My Input will be : **APPLE/A0AB**

I need the output is : **A0AB**

So the main thing that "/" and everything before of that sign should be reduce.

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: You should get yourself a hpc (highly paid consultant) or show us some of your effort

Comment: I would recommend regular expressions. But could you show us some of your sample code?

Comment: "I need a C# program" is not a good start here on StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Please risk a look on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Take a look at the [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx#Methods) of the `String` class and see if there's anything that you can use...

Comment: Sorry for my bad manner but need some help from expert .

Comment: As an addition to @Kempeth comment, you should also read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/index

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Rextester
{
  public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 string input=" APPLE/A0AB";
Console.WriteLine(input.Split('/')[1]);
}
}
}
```

OUTPUT:
A0AB

RUN ONLINE:
http://rextester.com/QJE14484

Comment: But there is a problem if the number of '/' is unknown. In that case what should i do.

Comment: @SiyamSarker That depends on what you WANT the program to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SubString` method.

```
input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

You code should be like :-

```
 string input = " APPLE/A0AB";
 string output = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: I got it but suppose you don't know how many "/" will be in string then what should i do.

Comment: @SiyamSarker rephrase your question to include this piece of information into your problem description

Comment: @SiyamSarker what will you do when your string is `APPLE/A0AB/PEAR/P0AP` which part will you reduce?

Comment: Before of last "/" all string will be remove.

Comment: If you only want the string after the last "/" use LastIndexOf instread of IndexOf in the above answer

Comment: Thanks. Its Works.

Comment: @SiyamSarker you could at least repay the favor the Santosh did you by writing the code for you with accepting his answer. If you don't know how here is a [post that shows how to do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)